# How do I get ffigen to work with Dart 2.3.0?

Tags: flutter, dart, ffi

I am trying to use ffigen to generate bindings for the C-based mbedtls codebase so that I can use it with Dart. In my pubspec.yaml file I'm using v2.3.0 of the Dart sdk and v7.2.10 of ffigen.

However when I run

```
dart run ffigen
```

the Dart bindings file that gets generated has compilation errors involving the "late" keyword. For example, here's a snippet of the code that gets automatically generated:

```
void __va_start(
    ffi.Pointer<va_list> arg0,
  ) {
    return ___va_start(
      arg0,
    );
  }

  late final ___va_startPtr =
      _lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Void Function(ffi.Pointer<va_list>)>>(
          '__va_start');
  late final ___va_start =
      ___va_startPtr.asFunction<void Function(ffi.Pointer<va_list>)>();
```

The compiler is complaining stating: "Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'..."

This error goes away if I specify sdk v2.13.0 in my pubspec.yaml file, but I need to use v2.3.0. How can I get these bindings to compile with a newer version of the sdk, like v2.3.0?

Thanks in advance.